# How to prevent the bottom line from crossing the text

Tags: tables, multirow

```
\begin{table}[]
\small
\begin{tabular}{|m{5em}|m{8em}|m{8em}|m{8em}|m{4em}|}
\hline
\centering \tiny \textbf{Ref.,$1^{st}$ Author, Year of Publication} & \multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{2.6cm}{\centering \tiny \textbf{Smart Material Actuator Characteristics}}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\tiny \textbf{Pump}} \\\cdashline{1-1} \cline{3-5} 

\multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{1.7cm}{\centering \tiny \textbf{Analytical (A), Numerical (N), Experimental (E) Work}}} &    & \centering \tiny \textbf{Structural Characteristics} & \centering \tiny \textbf{Operating Characteristics and Performance Properties} & \multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{1.5cm}{\centering \tiny \textbf{Potential Applications}}}\\ \cline{2-4}

& \tiny \textbf{Actuator Type} Material/s, Geometry, Length (\emph{l}), Width (\emph{w}), Diameter (\emph{d}), Thickness (\emph{t}) ($\mu$m or mm) & \tiny \textbf{Pump (P)}: Geometry, \emph{l}, \emph{w}, Height (\emph{h}), \emph{d} (mm), Volume (\emph{V}) ($mm^{3}$); \textbf{Pump Chamber (PC)}: Number (\#), Geometry, \emph{l}, \emph{w}, \emph{h} (mm); \textbf{Inlet/Outlet (I/O) Flow Rectification Mechanism of Pump} & \tiny \textbf{Voltage \emph{U}} (V), \textbf{Current \emph{I}} (A); \textbf{Frequency \emph{f}} (Hz); \textbf{Maximum, Average Flow Rate $Q_{max}$, $Q_{av}$} (mL or $\mu$L/min); \textbf{Maximum Back-pressure $\Delta p_{max}$}  (kPa); Medium Transported&   \\ \hline

\tiny \cite{benard1998thin}, 1998 & \multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{2.7cm}{\tiny \textbf{Biased Bulk (Sheet)} (U-SMAs in antagonistic conformation) Ni-Ti (passive cooling), Tetragonal, \emph{l} = \emph{w} = 8.4 mm, \emph{t} = 3 $\mu$m}}& \multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{2.7cm}{\tiny \textbf{P:} Rectangular, \textbf{PC:} \# = 1, \textbf{IO:} Passive (polyimide) valves\\}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{2.7cm}{\tiny \emph{\textbf{U}} = 0.6 V, \emph{\textbf{I}} = 0.9 A, \emph{\textbf{f}} = 0.9 Hz, \emph{\textbf{$Q_{max}$}} = 49 $\mu$L/min, \emph{\textbf{$\Delta p_{max}$}} = 0.53 kPa; Water}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{1.4cm}{\tiny Micro-fluidic device}} \\ \cdashline{1-1}

\tiny E  &  &   &  &  \\ \hline

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: I'd suggest trying to redesign the first column in order to avoid tge need for multirow. You could for example use table notes to specify which category a reference belongs to.

Comment: See the multi row documentation (`texdoc multi row`), section 3.8 Dealing with tall entries.

Comment: Should me `multirow` in my previous comment. Something inserted unintended spaces.

Answer (score 2):

You can do two things to solve the problem

(1) Use a parbox as wide as the width of the columns allows, and

(2) Add an extra row to accommodate the overflow lines of the last cell of the second column.

[image: A]

Only the last row from your code was modified.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\author{The Author}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{table}[]
        \small
        \begin{tabular}{|m{5em}|m{8em}|m{8em}|m{8em}|m{4em}|}
            \hline
            \centering \tiny \textbf{Ref.,$1^{st}$ Author, Year of Publication} & \multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{2.6cm}{\centering \tiny \textbf{Smart Material Actuator Characteristics}}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\tiny \textbf{Pump}} \\\cdashline{1-1} \cline{3-5} 
            
            \multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{1.7cm}{\centering \tiny \textbf{Analytical (A), Numerical (N), Experimental (E) Work}}} &    & \centering \tiny \textbf{Structural Characteristics} & \centering \tiny \textbf{Operating Characteristics and Performance Properties} & \multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{1.5cm}{\centering \tiny \textbf{Potential Applications}}}\\ \cline{2-4}
            
            & \tiny \textbf{Actuator Type} Material/s, Geometry, Length (\emph{l}), Width (\emph{w}), Diameter (\emph{d}), Thickness (\emph{t}) ($\mu$m or mm) & \tiny \textbf{Pump (P)}: Geometry, \emph{l}, \emph{w}, Height (\emph{h}), \emph{d} (mm), Volume (\emph{V}) ($mm^{3}$); \textbf{Pump Chamber (PC)}: Number (\#), Geometry, \emph{l}, \emph{w}, \emph{h} (mm); \textbf{Inlet/Outlet (I/O) Flow Rectification Mechanism of Pump} & \tiny \textbf{Voltage \emph{U}} (V), \textbf{Current \emph{I}} (A); \textbf{Frequency \emph{f}} (Hz); \textbf{Maximum, Average Flow Rate $Q_{max}$, $Q_{av}$} (mL or $\mu$L/min); \textbf{Maximum Back-pressure $\Delta p_{max}$}  (kPa); Medium Transported&   \\ \hline
            
            %% CHANGED <<<<<<
            \tiny \cite{benard1998thin}, 1998 & \multirow{2}{*}{\parbox[t]{8em}{\tiny \textbf{Biased Bulk (Sheet)} (U-SMAs in antagonistic conformation) Ni-Ti (passive cooling), Tetragonal, \emph{l} = \emph{w} = 8.4 mm, \emph{t} = 3 $\mu$m}}& \multirow{2}{*}{\parbox[t]{8em}{\tiny \textbf{P:} Rectangular, \textbf{PC:} \# = 1, \textbf{IO:} Passive (polyimide) valves\\}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\parbox[t]{8em}{\tiny \emph{\textbf{U}} = 0.6 V, \emph{\textbf{I}} = 0.9 A, \emph{\textbf{f}} = 0.9 Hz, \emph{\textbf{$Q_{max}$}} = 49 $\mu$L/min, \emph{\textbf{$\Delta p_{max}$}} = 0.53 kPa; Water}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\parbox[t]{4em}{\tiny Micro-fluidic device}} \\ \cdashline{1-1}          
            \tiny E  &  &   &  &  \\
            &  &   &  &  \\ % added <<<
             \hline
            
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table} 
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: +! a nice visual impact

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest redesigning the column headers:

[image]

In the following MWE, I also used the `siunitx` for some of the numbers and their units. Others should be adjusted accordingly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{threeparttable}
\small
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{5em}|*{3}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X|}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2cm}|}
\hline
 \multirow{4}{=}{\textbf{Ref\tnote{a}}} &  \multirow{4}{=}{\textbf{Smart Material Actuator Characteristics\tnote{b}}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Pump}} \\ \cline{3-5} 

 &    & \textbf{Structural Characteristics\tnote{c}} &  \textbf{Operating Characteristics and Performance Properties\tnote{d}} & \textbf{Potential Applications}\\
\hline

\cite{benard1998thin}, 1998 (E) 
   &  \textbf{Biased Bulk (Sheet)} (U-SMAs in antagonistic conformation) Ni-Ti (passive cooling), Tetragonal, \emph{l} = \emph{w} = \SI{8.4}{\mm}, \emph{t} = \SI{3}{\um}
   & \textbf{P:} Rectangular, \textbf{PC:} \# = 1, \textbf{IO:} Passive (polyimide) valves 
   & \emph{\textbf{U}} = 0.6 V, \emph{\textbf{I}} = 0.9 A, \emph{\textbf{f}} = 0.9 Hz, \emph{\textbf{$Q_{max}$}} = 49 $\mu$L/min, \emph{\textbf{$\Delta p_{max}$}} = 0.53 kPa; Water
   & Micro-fluidic device \\ 
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[a] 1\textsuperscript{st} Author \& Year of Publication, A = Analytical, N = Numerical, E = Experimental Work
\item[b] \textbf{Actuator Type} Material/s, Geometry, Length (\emph{l}), Width (\emph{w}), Diameter (\emph{d}), Thickness (\emph{t}) (\si{\um} or \si{mm})
\item[c]  \textbf{Pump (P)}: Geometry, \emph{l}, \emph{w}, Height (\emph{h}), \emph{d} (\si{\mm}), Volume (\emph{V}) (\si{\cubic\mm}); \textbf{Pump Chamber (PC)}: Number (\#), Geometry, \emph{l}, \emph{w}, \emph{h} (\si{\mm}); \textbf{Inlet/Outlet (I/O) Flow Rectification Mechanism of Pump}
\item[d]  \textbf{Voltage \emph{U}} (V), \textbf{Current \emph{I}} (A); \textbf{Frequency \emph{f}} (Hz); \textbf{Maximum, Average Flow Rate $Q_{max}$, $Q_{av}$} (mL or $\mu$L/min); \textbf{Maximum Back-pressure $\Delta p_{max}$}  (kPa); Medium Transported
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution which (a) employs a `tabularx` environment, (b) gets rid of all `\tiny` directives and uses a single `\footnotesize` directive instead, (c) does away with all `\multirow` directives, and (d) takes care to typeset scientific units in a way that satisfies standard formatting requirements.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage{tabularx,amsmath,arydshln,ragged2e} 
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X}
\usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx} % for \si and \SI macros

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default: 6pt
\footnotesize
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|C|L|L|L|L|}
\hline
\textbf{Ref., First Author, Year of Publication} &
\textbf{Smart Material Actuator Characteristics} & 
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Pump}} \\
\cdashline{1-1} 
\cline{3-5} 
Type of Work: Analytical (A), Numerical (N), Experimental (E) & &
\textbf{Structural Characteristics} & 
\textbf{Operating Characteristics and Performance Properties} & \textbf{Potential Applications}\\ 
\cline{2-4}
& \textbf{Actuator Type} Material/s, Geometry, Length $l$, Width $w$, Diameter $d$, Thickness $t$ (\si{\um} or \si{\mm}) & 
\textbf{Pump (P)}: Geometry $l, w$, Height $h, d$ (\si{\mm}), Volume $V$ (\si{\mm\cubed}); \newline
\textbf{Pump Chamber (PC)}: Number (\#), Geometry $l, w, h$ (\si{\mm}); \newline 
\textbf{Inlet/Outlet (I/O) Flow Rectification Mechanism of Pump} & 
\textbf{Voltage} $U$ (\si{\volt}); 
\textbf{Current} $I$ (\si{\ampere}); 
\mbox{\textbf{Frequency}} $f$ (\si{\hertz}); \newline
\textbf{Maximum, Average Flow Rate} $Q_{\max}$, $Q_{\mathrm{av}}$ (\si{\milli\liter} or \si{\micro\liter\per\minute}); \newline
\textbf{Maximum Back-pressure} $\Delta p_{\max}$  (\si{\kilo\pascal}); \newline Medium Transported &   \\ 
\hline

\cite{benard1998thin}, 1998 \newline (E)& 
\textbf{Biased Bulk (Sheet)} (U-SMAs in antagonistic conformation) Ni\nobreakdash-Ti (passive cooling), Tetragonal, $l = w = \SI{8.4}{\mm}$, $t = \SI{3}{\um}$ & 
\textbf{P}: Rectangular, \newline
\textbf{PC}: \# = 1, \newline
\textbf{IO}: Passive (polyimide) valves & 
$U = \SI{0.6}{\volt}$, 
$I = \SI{0.9}{\ampere}$, 
$f= \SI{0.9}{\hertz}$, 
$Q_{\max} = \SI{49}{\micro\liter\per\minute}$, 
$\Delta p_{\max} = \SI{0.53}{\kilo\pascal}$; 
Water & 
Micro-fluidic device \\ 
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```